# Can't run Pandas DataFrame operations after using .pivot()

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm using .pivot() to turn data that looks like this:

```
ID / Month / Value
1 / Jan / 10
1 / Feb / 11
2 / Jan / 14
2 / Feb / 17
3 / Jan / 19
3 / Feb / 19
```

Into this:

```
ID / Jan / Feb
1 / 10 / 11
2 / 14 / 17
3/ 19 / 19
```

I ran this to achieve that:

```
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Month', values='Value').reset_index()
```

Which works just fine, except I can no longer run DataFrame operations when I do that. For instance, if I do:

```
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Month', values='Value').reset_index()
df.info()
```

I get a big error message with not much in the way of useful info aside from "KeyError: 0".

I tried a few other approaches to this, but I always either end up with multi-index columns (which I don't want) or I can't conduct any operations.

Is there a way around this or a better solution?

Comment: cannot reproduce the KeyError after I fix a typo: `df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Month', values='Value').reset_index()`

Comment: I concur.  works fine for me.

Comment: If you really fixed it by a `copy()` and not anything additional, I think that's a bug

Comment: Turns out I was wrong about that; was accidentally copying the earlier (unpivoted) dataframe which did work.